# using the xboxdrv exec function

Tags: raspbian, emulation

I have setup an Xbox360 wireless controller for the Rpi2 following [this](http://www.s-config.com/chinese-xbox-360-wireless-receiver-driver-setup/) tutorial using xboxdrv:

I am launching xboxdrv via init as described [here](https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/wiki/Setting-up-the-XBox360-controller).

It should be possible to launch applications such as EmulationStation from a terminal via xboxdrv using its 'exec' button filter.  But here I am having problems.

Even executing something as simple as **ls** will display the expected output, but the command prompt does not reappear after the output.  A RETURN keypress is required to bring it back.
For EmulationStation problems are encountered when starting an emulator.  This executes the **runcommand.sh** script which then returns errors regarding the existance of **/dev/tty**.

Is there a connection between the loss of the command prompt when using the exec button filter and /dev/tty (I understand this to be the current virtual terminal)?